# Using GetValue inside of Where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, linq, reflection

I have an api in asp.net core (I am new to apis btw), and I am trying to have the results filtered by a class property, and that properties value. If I have a class named `info` and its properties are `attack`, `defense`, etc... the types of the properties are `int`. The user wants to see results where `attack > 5` or `defense > 7` etc... Here are my classes:

```
public class Champion
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string blurb { get; set; }
    public info info { get; set; }
    public string[] tags { get; set; }
    //etc
}
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, Champion> data { get; set; }
}
public class info
{
    public int attack { get; set; }
    public int defense { get; set; }
    public int magic { get; set; }
    public int difficulty { get; set; }
}
public class stats
{
    public double hp { get; set; }
    public double hpperlevel { get; set; }
    public double mp { get; set; }
    public double mpperlevel { get; set; }
    //etc
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
[HttpGet("{property}/{value}")]    //property is attack, defense, etc
public ActionResult Get(string property, int value)
{
    var json = //json string;
    var champions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json); 
    info i = new info { };

    //Here is what I am trying to implement
    var returnValues = champions.data.Values
                          .Where(x => x.info.GetType()
                               .GetProperty(property)
                               .GetValue(i, null) > value);

    //remaining code and return statement;
}
```

What I would like to do is use `returnValues` as a list of all of the values in the `champions` object

`Where(x => x.property > value).ToList()`.

When I use `GetType().GetProperty().GetValue() > value` I am attempting to compare an object to an `int` `.Where` requires a `bool` to filter. So my question is how I can implement this? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast that object to actual type of the property. In this case, it is an `int`. In addition, you don't need the other `null` parameter. Just `GetValue(yourObject)` will work. You call it and cast it to the type of your property.

Try this:

```cs
var returnValues = champions.data.Values
    .Where(x => (int) (x.info.GetType()
        .GetProperty(property)
        .GetValue(x.info)) > value);
```

Comment: This is good, in `.GetValue(i, null)` change `i` to `x.info` and it works. I will accept it but just fix that.

Comment: Thanks, I guess all along I needed to cast. It is a really simple question, just wasn't thinking.

Comment: @stupidQuestions Yes, whenever you use Reflection with `GetValue(object)`, you should cast it to your actual type.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
x.info.GetType().GetProperties()
 .Where(y=> y.Name.ToLower() == property.ToLower())
 .FirstOrDefault().GetValue(x.info) > value
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rffk4.png

Comment: First of all, what is `y => y.Name`? Is `Name` a part of the Reflection class? But it doesn't work anyway, the inner `Where` clause says `PropertyInfo does not contain a definition for Where`

Comment: y => y.Name: your property name. GetValue takes an object from that class and return object.Can you try? int.Parse(x.info.GetType().GetProperties().Where(y=> y.Name.ToLower() == property.ToLower()).FirstOrDefault().GetValue(x.info).ToString() )> value

Comment: I feel like there is progress though. Yes I will try this too. I did not see that comment.